# List of Bluetooth devices on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, bonjour, gamekit

I'm develop iphone app, what need connect to bluetooth device and handle disconnection of device.

I'm tryied to use ExternalAccessory framework, but it don't show any device (in settings I have paired A2DP device), on apple site I see " Specifically, you must include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key to declare the specific hardware protocols your application supports.", I think problem in this, but I don't know what is protocol strings for A2DP example.

Few questions:

1. have any idea how make what I want via other tech (GameKit or Bonjour example);
2. somebody maybe know standart protocol strings for A2DP like devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have signed up for Apple's "Made for iPod" program you will have no access to bluetooth, beyond the API's offered by the GameKit framework, which can only communicate with other iOS devices, running your software,